# CSS - overflow hidden for an entire <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

I'm outputting a list of `<li>` elements  and I want to apply `overflow:hidden` on my `<ul>` so if any `<li>` doesn't fit it will be hidden **completely**, not only part of it.

Here is my list:

```
<ul style="height: 500px; overflow:hidden;">
  <li>Some big text goes here</li>
  <li>Some big text goes here</li>
  <li>Some big text goes here</li>
  <li>Some big text goes here</li>
</ul>
```

is it possible to do it with pure CSS+HTML?

Comment: only if your `height` is a multiple of the `line-height` and also the `li` elements are single lines.. The moment a `li` element has more than one line, you cannot make it hide when half is out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would only work with two requirements (*in pure CSS*)..

1. The `li` elements do not wrap their contents (*use `white-space:nowrap;`*)
2. The `height` of the `ul` is a multiple of the `line-height` of the `li`

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/A36fN/

---

Alternatively you could write some javascript to detect the overflow and hide the elements that need to..

Comment: Thank you! `white-space:nowrap;` did the trick for me. I was trying all those other tips about positions, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any *pure css* solution for your issue.

You will have to use javascript to achieve what you are trying. What you need to do is calculate height of your container and then calculate height of all child elements, if they don't fit in, set last element `display:none`

take a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722191/hide-li-element-when-not-fully-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that isn't possible in pure HTML + CSS.

For example, if I have 5 `<li>`'s in a row, and the `font-size` for them is 16px, with the line height being 20px, then I would need to set the `<ul>` height to be 5 * 20 to display each `<li>` in its entirety. That would work fine until someone increases the font size in their browser, or one of those `<li>`'s goes over two lines.

[Example of working fine](http://jsfiddle.net/8M927/) (Notice that the 6th li is not showing.)

[Example of not working](http://jsfiddle.net/fazK7/1/)

Comment: You could use `em` units for font-size and height plus unitless line-height: it will be fine whatever the base font-size set by user

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y8p2X/2/ where font-size is a multiple of parent (by default body at 16px most of the time) and line-height 1.5 times that, whatever the font-size. As 6em (height) is a multiple of 1.5, that'll be fine.