# Horizontal list show item only if it gets displayed fully

Tags: image, css, horizontal-scrolling

I want to show images in a horizontal list. The list won't break into a second row (controlled by `white-space: nowrap`) and hides overflow.

The problem is that an image could be be shown only partially (depending on viewport width and the amount of images) - I want to avoid that by don't displaying it all if it can't be shown to 100%.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #555;
}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li .image {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="image"></div></li>
    <li><div class="image"></div></li>
    <li><div class="image"></div></li>
    <li><div class="image"></div></li>
    <li><div class="image"></div></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here a [sample pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZNvjL?editors=110) - I use divs instead of images to simplify things.

The red one in this example should be hidden

[image]

Images have always the same size, 320x180px

I'm not sure if this is even possible with CSS only - But I'm not a big friend of fixing styles with JS - so I thought I'll ask SO.

Comment: "Hide <li> element when not fully visible": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722191/hide-li-element-when-not-fully-visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the detailed media queries approach. You'll have to do the math, to get the correct break point and `width` for the `ul`. i.e. there are 4 images total, `320px` width for each plus `10px` margin, to display all of them the number would be `320x4+10x8=1360`, so the break point would be `1360-1=1359`, and so on for 3//2/1 image(s). The whole media queries set looks like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1359px) { ul {width: 1020px;} }
@media (max-width: 1019px) { ul {width: 680px;} }
@media (max-width: 679px)  { ul {width: 340px;} }
@media (max-width: 339px)  { ul {width: 0;} }
```

See the complete demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obxRMM?editors=110

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
ul li .image {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 320px;
  height: 180px;
}
@media (max-width: 1359px) { ul {width: 1020px;} }
@media (max-width: 1019px) { ul {width: 680px;} }
@media (max-width: 679px)  { ul {width: 340px;} }
@media (max-width: 339px)  { ul {width: 0;} }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="image"></div></li>
  <li><div class="image"></div></li>
  <li><div class="image"></div></li>
  <li><div class="image"></div></li>
</ul>
```